# Django form. How to post a string in form and save it as objects id?

Tags: django, forms, validation, post

I have a model for adverts which has a relation to Towns model. This model contains a list of towns which have some meta data.

In my form I've implemented ajax autocomplete for towns. Each town has a name_unique field and based on this data autocomplete helps with filling the input form.

However, I actually need a relationship to Town.id not Town.name_unique.

How I can perform such action so django form will accept a name_unique value and save it as actual 'id' of town?

How to post in form a string and save it as

```
class Advert(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = u"Ogłoszenie"
        verbose_name_plural = u"Ogłoszenia"
        ordering = ['-date_added', ]

    title = models.CharField(verbose_name="Tytuł ogłoszenia", max_length=32)
    text = models.TextField(verbose_name="Treść ogłoszenia", max_length=3000)

    location = models.ForeignKey("division.Towns", verbose_name="Miejscowość")



class AdvertForm(ModelForm):
    category = CustomTreeNodeChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.filter(parent__isnull=False),
                                         empty_label="Wybierz kategorię", label="Kategoria")

    class Meta:
        model = Advert
        exclude = ('ip', 'user', 'first_name', 'last_name')
        widgets = {
            'location': TextInput
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        super(AdvertForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)



def add(request):
    form = AdvertForm(request.POST or None, request=request)

    if form.is_valid():
        advert = form.save(commit=False)
        advert.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('adverts.views.detail', kwargs={'pk': advert.pk}))

    return TemplateResponse(request, "adverts/add.html", {'form': form, })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used the JQuery-Autocomplete for that and combined that with a custom FormField/Widget. Basicly the widget renders two input-fields, one hidden containing the id and one visible containing the text-representation and the autocomplete-logic:

```
<input type="text" class="ac_input" name="%(name)s_text" id="%(html_id)s_text" value="%(text)s"/>
<input type="hidden" name="%(name)s" id="%(html_id)s" value="%(value)s" />
```

If the autocomplete-field is changed, it loads a dictionary from the server in the form of `[{id: "..", text:""}, ...]` and sets the text-field to contain the value of text and the hidden id-field to id. This way the hidden id-field is used by the form and it contains the id you want. 
I uploaded my code to a pastebin (link: http://pastebin.com/LncqfQM2). The code is a bit older and the comments are half-missing, half-german, sorry :/
In the form i use:

```
ort = AutocompleteModelChoiceField(Ort.objects, url=reverse("orte-autocompletecallback"))
```

And in the View:

```
def callback(request):
    # some code loading the objects
    return [{'id': row.pk, 'label':row.name} for row in objects]
```

I hope this helps.

edit: I started reworking bits of the code (Tidy it up a bit, comments, examples). If im finished i post another link in / edit the old link.

Comment: Here is the (Somewhat untested for lack of unittests :/) update of the code:
http://pastebin.com/LncqfQM2